# How to make a part of string variable bold

Tags: php

Lets say I have a string variable goes like this:

```
$pro_details = 'Main Information: Goes Here';
```

Now I want to separate this variable into two pieces by the **:** sign. So one of the parts would be `Main Information` and the other part is `Goes Here`.

Then I want to make bold the 1st part Which is `Main Information`. So the output of this variable after this process would be:

**Main Information:** Goes Here

Till now I just know how to break down a variable like this:

```
$pro_details = explode(':', $row_results['pro_details']);
```

But I don't know how to make bold the first part just like I told you.

So, if you know how to solve this, please let me know.. thanks in advance!

===========================================================================

**UPDATE 1:**

Since I have 3 variables like the one I discussed about it here, I coded this:

```
 $pro_details1 = explode(':', $row_results['product_details1']);
 $pro_details1[0] = "<strong>{$pro_details1[0]}</strong>";
 $pro_details2 = explode(':', $row_results['product_details2']);
 $pro_details2[0] = "<strong>{$pro_details2[0]}</strong>";
 $pro_details3 = explode(':', $row_results['product_details3']);
 $pro_details3[0] = "<strong>{$pro_details3[0]}</strong>";
```

And I tried echoing them like this:

```
if (!empty($pro_details1)||(!empty($pro_details2))||(!empty($pro_details3))){
    echo "
        <p>
        <ul class='BHamid' style='font-size:25px;'>
    ";
    if(!empty($pro_details1)){
        echo "                                  
            <li>$pro_details1[0]:$pro_details1[1]</li>
        ";
    }
    if(!empty($pro_details2)){
        echo "
            <li>$pro_details2[0]:$pro_details2[1]</li>
        ";
    }
    if(!empty($pro_details3)){
        echo "
            <li>$pro_details3[0]:$pro_details3[1]</li>
        ";
    }
    echo "
        </ul>
        </p>
    ";
}
```

And then this error comes up:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 13

Line 13:

```
<li>$pro_details2[0]:$pro_details2[1]</li>
```

Because I set the 2nd `pro_details` (which is `$pro_details2`) empty in the table to see how this code works if one of the fields is empty.

So I need a way out of this error, because sometimes one of the `pro_details` variables can be NULL due to the project that I'm working on.

Comment: the ": sign" is called a colon :)

Comment: You don't make a string variable bold,  apply css to the html that contains the string

Comment: Please go through css code  like font weight   `https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp` Or  in simple way  you can use `<b> <?php echo $pro_details[0] </b>`

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript using split()

Comment: Assuming _make bold_ means in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode on the colon just like you said...

```
 $pro_details = explode(':', $row_results['pro_details']);
```

Then wrap the first one in a `<b>` tag which makes it bold when rendered in the broswer.

```
$pro_details[0] = "<b>{$pro_details[0]}</b>";
```

Then implode them again.

```
$pro_details = implode(':', $pro_details);
```

And there you go... `echo $pro_details;`

---

I would make a function so you're not repeating yourself so much.

```
function boldifyTitle($pd){
    $pd = explode(':', $pd);
    $pd[0] = "<b>$pd</b>";
    if(empty($pd[1])) $pd[1] = "";
    return implode(':', $pd);
}

echo "<li>".boldifyTitle($pro_details[0])."</li>";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works but I faced a new error `Undefined offset`. I just updated the question about this problem. Please checkout **UPDATE 1**, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What about preg_replace:

```
$pro_details = 'Main Information: Goes Here';
echo preg_replace('/(.*):/', '<b>$1:</b>', $pro_details);
```

This captures everything before the colon and wraps it in  tags.

Output:

```
<b>Main Information:</b> Goes Here
```

preg_replace uses regular expressions to search for patterns and to replace those patterns with something else. See the docs on the PHP site. [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Briefly:

The first arg is the search pattern. Books have been written on regular expressions so I won't go into it here other than to explain the example.

`/(.*):/` means to search for a sequence of any character up to a colon ':'.

. means any character
* means 0 or more of the preceding character.

The parens `()` are used to capture that sequence so it can be used in the replace side. The `$1` in the second parameter is the sequence of characters that was found inside the parens in the search parameter.

If I wrote this in English, it would read as follows:
Find a sequence of characters up to but not including a colon. Replace that sequence of characters by prefixing `<b>` and suffixing `</b>`, leaving the rest of the string unmodified.

One other thing to note. In this specific case, we could actually use `str_replace()` because we know the opening bold tag goes at the beginning.

```
echo '<b>' . str_replace(':', ':</b>', $pro_details);
```

Comment: What do u mean by $1 in your answer?